# Enabling bootstrap content assist in eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way in which I can enable bootstrap content-assist in eclipse ? I tried adding bootstrap js to javascript path that did not help .

[image: Bootstrap JS in javascript path]

Comment: I have the same problem. Content Assist seems to work for the theme files, but not for the other two Bootstrap css files. Let us know if you figure this out. Thanks, M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of the tern.java.

I suggest you that you [install tern.java 0.10.0](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) (not released) which provides a [tern support for Bootstrap](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Bootstrap-support) with completion for bootstrap :

[image]